# C++ map iterator jump elements

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert, iterator

I have a question about std::map structure: 
this code fragment works correctly:

```
map<string,int> mappa;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
mappa["b"]=1;
mappa["a"]=2;
 for(std::map<string,int>::iterator it=mappa.begin();it!=mappa.end();++it )
{
    cout<<it->first<<"\n";     
} 
return 0;
}
```

output:

```
a
b
```

but if I do:

```
map<string,int> mappa; 
std::map<string,int> getList(){
return mappa;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
mappa["b"]=1;
mappa["a"]=2;
for(std::map<string,int>::iterator it=getList().begin();it!=getList().end();++it )
 {
    cout<<it->first<<"\n";   
 } 
return 0;
}
```

my output is just

```
b
```

why?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `getList` multiple times. Each time it creates a new map using the copy constructor.

You such do this:

```
std::map<string,int> myList = getList();
const std::map<string,int>::iterator myListEnd = myList.end();
for(std::map<string,int>::iterator myList.begin();it!=myListEnd;++it )
{
```

I am assuming that you require a copy.

Comment: I don't understand..I have two copies of the same map...begin() and end() don't return the same values in both copies?

Comment: @user1973451 - In your question your function getList constructs a copy of the map. You use different copies for initialising the iterator and working out when it reaches the end.

Answer (score 4):

In the for loop, you are taking your begin() and end() from 2 separate copies of mappa as getList() is returning by value instead of reference. You need to change your getList() function to return by reference.

Code that works as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

map<string,int> mappa; 

std::map<string,int>& getList() { // returning reference now
  return mappa;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  mappa["b"]=1;
  mappa["a"]=2;
  for(std::map<string,int>::iterator it=getList().begin();it!=getList().end();++it )
  {
    cout<<it->first<<"\n";   
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok but...why? I have two copies of the same map...begin() and end() don't return the same value in both copies?

Answer (score 1):

getList() returns a copy of mappa.  You need to change it to return a reference:

```
std::map<string,int>& getList()
```

or even better a const reference:

```
const std::map<string,int>& getList()
```

In the latter case you will need to use const_iterator to iterate over the map.